# JavaScript for loop different order

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why I get different order everytime the code loops?
I'm very new to JavaScript and I know the code isn't very neat.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="status">

<br>
</div>
<script>
LoopThis()

function LoopThis(){


document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status - Name: <br>"
var USERLIST = ["amd","danielfromsl","skyrimfus","tyler1","andymilonakis","OMGchad","Russ_Money","h3h3productions"]
var i, len;

for (i = 0, len = USERLIST.length; i < len; i++){

USERCHECK = USERLIST[i]

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        JSONDOC = this.responseText;
        last = JSONDOC.split('"mature":')
        last = last[1]
        last = last.split(",")
        isonline = last[0]
        streamtitle = last[1].split('"status":')
        streamtitle = streamtitle[1]
        realuser = last[3].split('"display_name":')
        realuser = realuser[1]
        realuser = realuser.split('"')
        realuser = realuser[1]
        url = last[15].split('"url":')
        url = url[1]
        url = url.split('"')
        url = url[1]
     if (isonline == "true") {
        //alert(realuser+" is streaming! Title:"+streamtitle)
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += "<font color='0x00FF00'>Online</font> - "+"<a href='"+url+"'>"+realuser+"</a><br>"
      } else { 
        //alert(realuser+" is offline!")
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += "<font color='red'>Offline</font> - "+realuser+"<br>"
     }



    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+USERCHECK+"?client_id=Sky", true);
  xhttp.send();

}
}

setInterval(LoopThis,5000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The loading time of the each call varies depending on tens of different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a for loop to loop through the list of users in a predefined order.
But inside the loop you make an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest and you give it a function that will run when you receive a response for that request. The function you have attached to the xhttp.onreadystatechange event will run **when a response is received.**

The responses can be received in a different order everytime the script is run and that's why the  different xhttp.onreadystatechange events will fire in a different order.

Comment: Is there a way to make it consistent?

Comment: You use colors to differentiate between online and offline, right? You could display all of the names in the order you prefer in grey and then use the for loop to iterate all of them and only change their color based on their status. That way the order doens't depend on the responses you will receive.